# Postgres cast MI:SS formatted string to "interval minute to second" type

Tags: postgresql, datetime, postgresql-13, interval

I have a data source with the time information being formatted like this: 'MI:SS'.

I am trying to coerce that to a native postgres INTERVAL or TIME type so I can leverage the equivalent operators.

I have tried the following:

```sql
        CASE
            WHEN (event."BIDASK" = 'BP') THEN '10:00'
            WHEN (event."MARKERTIME" = '00:-1') OR (event."MARKERTIME" = '') THEN '00:00'
            ELSE event."MARKERTIME"
        END ::interval minute to second
```

event."MARKERTIME" is a "MM:SS" formatted string.

I note however that it gets converted to 'HH:MM' in the casted interval type.

ie. for the string "10:00"

- I get: hours 10, minutes 00, seconds 00.
- I would expect: minutes 10, seconds 00

I am working on postgres 13.

Here is a db-fiddle illustrating this casting behaviour:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2QqG36bKnjAyjqecBKpDU/2

EDIT: One trick I find it working is to prepend the string with '00:' but I am hoping for a better way to achieve that because I cannot rely on the fact that the MI part of the string will be bounded between 0 and 59.

Comment: Can you add a https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13 that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Prepending the string with `00:` seems like a good solution. What's wrong with that?

Comment: I cannot rely on the fact that it will be always formatted MI:SS and that MI will be 0-60. @a_horse_with_no_name

 I will try add a dbfiddle which illustrates my scenario.

Comment: @Lennart please, find the attached db-fiddle in my (edited) post.